# Strange FontSize change

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I've encountered a strange thing today, working with [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms).

I've created a `RichTextBox` with default `FontSize` of 14.25 pt.

I was performing some operation and I needed to create temporary `RichTextBox` to which I have copied selected text fromy my original `RichtextBox`. After that, without no changes made by me, the whole tempRichTextBox text's font size increased exactly **0.25 pt**. Every single letter. Is that some bug or what?

```
using (RichTextBox tempRichTextBox = new RichTextBox())
{
    tempRichTextBox.Rtf = this.richTextBox.SelectedRtf;
    int tempStart = this.richTextBox.SelectionStart;
    int tempLength = this.richTextBox.SelectionLength;
    for (int i = 0; i < tempLength; i++)
    {
        tempRichTextBox.Select(i, 1);
        this.baseSize = tempRichTextBox.SelectionFont.Size;
    }
    tempRichTextBox.Select(0, tempLength);
    this.richTextBox.SelectedRtf = tempRichTextBox.SelectedRtf;
    this.richTextBox.Select(tempStart, tempLength);
}
```

Does anybody has an idea why is that happening?

Comment: Hmm, that's not something you can see.  How do you know?

Comment: @HansPassant What do you mean by that? I've checked the font size after copying. It was 14.50, before it was 14.25.

Comment: What *exactly* did you look at?   There's more than one.  The font size of the text in the RTB is provided by the SelectionFont property but only if SelectionStart is inside the text.

Comment: Inside the text? Okay, and if I have only one letter selected? As in my case, that I've given example code above?

Comment: @PawełPoręba, were you able to find the solution to the font size difference?

Comment: @JayakrishnanGounder Just look at the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I found that WinForms adds to font size (or sometimes subtracts from it) `0.25`. You see `14.25` in designer, but it is achieved because value `14` was initially stored there. I saw that happening also when playing with **FontDialog** system dialog alone. You choose font size 8 and in returned Font object you find 8.25. On some sizes I have found things like 14.75 instead of 15. But it is not growing with font size, i.e. you will find the same small differences with font size = 5000.

Cause: font size is changing in steps of 0.75. [It is related to DPI and font size units.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3605395/2392157)

So implement formula taking that into account and you should start getting more expectable results. Just note that DPI or font size units can be different in context of FontDialog and RTB.

Comment: I tried this one, but it still gets the same. But maybe it's too late, I'll try again tommorow and see if it works :)

Comment: @PawełPoręba – if you found some solution, please let us know :)

Comment: Hi:) I'm afraid I didn't. That is what I've noticed:
1) If you are working within only one RTB, while changing font size programatically, there is no need to round it. It will always have the same value as intended. But if you use FontDialog, the value will be changed based on DPI.
2) If you copy the content of your RTB to another one, the FontSize change on weird conditions. If I was passing the font size of 11.25, it would return 11.50, but if I was passing 11, it would return 11! So it's not the same as in 1), because 11.25 should return 11.25...

Answer (score 1):

That is interesting. I don't have an answer as to why, but the differences repeat every 3 pt font sizes.

```
void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    richTextBox.Text = "asdf";
    for (int i = 24; i <= 100; i++) {
        using (Font f = new Font(SystemFonts.DefaultFont.FontFamily, 1f * i / 4)) {
            richTextBox.SelectAll();
            richTextBox.SelectionFont = f;
            richTextBox.Font = f;
            sb.AppendLine(f.Size + "\t" + richTextBox.SelectionFont.Size + "\t" + Math.Round(f.Size - richTextBox.SelectionFont.Size, 3));
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer:) It seems like differences are sligtly different (bigger) when the text is being moved from one rtb to another. For instance, I set the SelectioFont of selected text to 14.25 in rtb1, copy it to rtb2, copy back to rtb1 (without doing anything to it) and the font is 14.50.