# How can get the correct font size in C# windows form?

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, richtextbox

I want to create a simple text editor in my C# WinForms Project.
I'm almost done, but I have a simple problem and I do not know how to fix this.
I want get the font name, size and style of the cursor position in real time, so I use the `SelectionChanged` event as below:

```
private void richTextBoxDefinition_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ChooseFontTextBox.Text = richTextBoxDefinition.SelectionFont.FontFamily.Name.ToString();
    StyleFontTextBox.Text = richTextBoxDefinition.SelectionFont.Style.ToString();
    SizeFontTextBox.Text = richTextBoxDefinition.SelectionFont.SizeInPoints.ToString();
}
```

in this code, size and font name are shown correctly, but the size has a problem.
For example if the font is 20, the text in SizeFontTextBox.Text shows 27.3
If the font is 14, the text in SizeFontTextBox.Text shows 13.5.

I try both `SizeInPoints` and `Size`, but the problem is not solved and the result is similar.

How can fix this?

Comment: What is the Unit of that font? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.font.unit?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0

Comment: I do not change Unit. so the Unit font of RichTextBox is Point.

Comment: How did you set the font?

Comment: with fontDialog (codeing)

Comment: Maybe relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544926/font-size-discrepancy-in-net-gdi

Comment: And also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/144866/font-dialog-not-returning-exact-font-size

Comment: thank you. with code in this link size is back correctly. I just need to set for the rich text box